# How to dynamically plot multiple subplots in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to plot a variable number of plots (at least 1 but it isn't known the number max) and I couldn't come up with a way to dynamically create and assign subplots to the given graphs.

The code looks like this:

```
check = False
    
    if "node_x_9" in names:
        if "node_x_11" in names:
            plt.plot(df["node_x_9"], df["node_x_11"])
            check = True
    elif "node_x_10" in names:
        if "node_x_12" in names:
            plt.plot(df["node_x_10", "node_x_12"])
            check = True
        
    if check:
        plt.show()
```

I thought about presetting a number of subplots (e.g. plt.subplots(3, 3)) but I still could not come up with a way to assign the plots without bounding them to a given subplot position.

My idea would be to create a 2x1 plot if I have two subplots, 1x1 if I have one, 3x1 if I have 3 and so on and not letting any subplot space empty.

Comment: so if I understood it correctly, you don't know number of plots you want to plot in advance right? Do you want to add subplots dynamically?

Comment: exactly, it's needed to study a database containing a number of nodes but it's unknown how many it will actually contain.

As for the second question yes, i'd like to assign them dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across cases like this, you want to generate one plot per case, but don't know how many cases exist until you query the data on the day.

I used a square layout as an assumption (alter the below if you require a different aspect ratio) then count how many cases you have - find the integer square-root, which, plus one, will give you the integer side-length of a square that is guaranteed to fit your requirements.

Now, you can establish a matplotlib [Gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html) object with the requisite width and height, referencing it by index to place your individual plots.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import random

# Create some random data with size=`random` number between 5 and 100
size = random.randint(5,100)
data_rows = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(1,5,25) for s in range(0,size)])

# Find the length of a (near) square based on the number of the data samples    
side_length = int(len(data_rows)**(1/2))+1
print(side_length)

#Create a gridspec object based on the side_length in both x and y dimensions
gs=gridspec.GridSpec(side_length, side_length)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

# Using the index i, populate the gridpsec object with 
# one plot per cell.
for i,row in data_rows.iterrows():
    ax=fig.add_subplot(gs[i])
    plt.bar(x=range(0,25),height=row)
```

[image: example plot layout]

Comment: If `len(data_rows)` is already a square number, then the `side_length` no need to add 1. You can add a condition : `int(len(data_rows)**(1/2)) if len(data_rows)**(1/2) == int(len(data_rows)**(1/2)) else int(len(data_rows)**(1/2))+1`

Comment: In hindsight, [math.ceil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) is probably a nice neat way to get the same behaviour, something like `side_length = ceil(len(data_rows)**(1/2))`

Comment: Yes, it looks neater this way. Thank you, learned.